# MySQL Group Replication - Peer address is not valid

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-innodb-cluster, group-replication

I have been trying to set up an *MySQL Innodb Cluster*, initially with two databases, both MySQL 8.0.19.

But I keep getting the same errors.

On the first one (`username@1.2.3.4:3306`), I have created the cluster, and that seems to be ok.

then I run:

`cluster.addInstance('username@1.2.3.5:3306')`

and get:

`ERROR: Unable to start Group Replication for instance 'dbname1:3306'. Please check the MySQL server error log for more information.
Cluster.addInstance: Group Replication failed to start: MySQL Error 3096 (HY000): dbname1:3306: The START GROUP_REPLICATION command failed as there was an error when initializing the group communication layer. (RuntimeError)`

From the errorlog on the second DB I get:

`[Warning] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Peer address "dbname:33061" is not valid.'
[ERROR] [MY-011735] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] None of the provided peer address is valid.'
[ERROR] [MY-011674] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Unable to initialize the group communication engine'
[ERROR] [MY-011637] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Error on group communication engine initialization'
[Note] [MY-011649] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Requesting to leave the group despite of not being a member'
[ERROR] [MY-011718] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Error calling group communication interfaces while trying to leave the group'`

My configuration thus far (from DB1) is:

`group_replication_ip_whitelist="1.2.3.4,1.2.3.5"
 group_replication_local_address="1.2.3.4:3306"
 group_replication_group_seeds="1.2.3.4:3306,1.2.3.5:3306"`

I thought maybe it was an issue with port **33061**, so I tried using port **33061** for MySQL's port, and **3306** for the Cluster CommunicationPort with 
`cluster.addInstance('username@1.2.3.5:33061',{localAddress:"dbname:3306"})`

But got the same errors.

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: any solution for this problem?